# WorksheetFunction.VLookup won't find match despite COUNTIF showing match is there

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a section of code where I have taken information from one tab and now need to match information from another tab. On the "Invoice Spreadsheet" tab, I have created a concatenated field that is the same order as the Match Test below, with no spaces or punctuation.

I've used a variation of this same code in another place and it worked just fine, but for some reason it won't work here. The `COUNTIF` function finds that the result exists, but I can't match to it.

I have tried to run this without the range variable `InvoiceRng` and just putting in the range, as well as with it. However I keep getting error 1004 that a match can't be found. Any ideas why this code won't work in this section, when I've used this similar layout multiple times with success?

```vb
Set InvoiceRng = Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("A3:AG" & LRInvoice)

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
      Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("I3:I" & LRInvoice), InvItem, _
      Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("Y3:Y" & LRInvoice), InvBill, _
      Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("Z3:Z" & LRInvoice), InvShip, _
      Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("AA3:AA" & LRInvoice), InvApp, _
      Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("H3:H" & LRInvoice), InvOrder) > 0 Then

    MatchTest = InvItem & InvOrder & InvBill & InvShip & InvApp

    'List Price
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MatchTest, InvoiceRng, 29, False)
    ActiveSheet.Range("I" & currentrow) = Match

    'Discount %
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MatchTest, InvoiceRng, 30, False)
    ActiveSheet.Range("K" & currentrow) = Match

    'Monthly Net
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MatchTest, InvoiceRng, 31, False)
    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & currentrow) = Match

    'Total Tax
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MatchTest, InvoiceRng, 32, False)
    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & currentrow) = Match

    'Total Amount
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MatchTest, InvoiceRng, 33, False)
    ActiveSheet.Range("N" & currentrow) = Match
End If
```

Comment: `I have created a concatenated field that is the same order as the Match Test` - and is that field the first column in `InvoiceRng`? Because that is where vlookup is going to look.

Comment: What are you doing with this:  `MatchTest = InvItem + InvOrder + InvBill + InvShip + InvApp`  Are you *summing* or *concatenating* ?

Comment: GSerg - The match should be in column AB.  I tried changing the range variable to: Set InvoiceRng = Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("AB3:AG" & LRInvoice), but its still throwing an error.

Comment: MatchTest = InvItem + InvOrder + InvBill + InvShip + InvApp is concatenating, they are all String variables.

Comment: VBA uses `&` for concatenation, that will avoid any accidental summing...

Comment: When using vlookup, the "match" column needs to be the *left-most column* in your lookup range.   `Set InvoiceRng = Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("AB3:AG" & LRInvoice)`  and change 29 >> 2 etc etc

Comment: `debug.? MatchTest`, then find the result on the sheet manually.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the + to &, not sure why I went with them in the first place.  However it still gives the same debug value for MatchTest.  I will give your suggestion a try and let you know how that goes.

Comment: I have used debug.Print, and the result does exist within that range.

Comment: I changed the range as suggested and that seems to fix my error.  Found a new one, but that one I think I can handle :)  Still not sure why it would matter here when I use the same code with a range that isn't the first column in another section, and it worked fine..... but thank you for the quick and fantastic help!

Comment: Then you should probably check that other scenario... with VLOOKUP, the match column *must* be the left-most column... no exceptions.

Comment: You're right, I just happened to be matching in column A on that one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the countifs, and just use Match:

```
Set InvoiceRng = Sheets("Invoice Spreadsheet").Range("AB3:AG" & LRInvoice)

MatchTest = InvItem & InvOrder & InvBill & InvShip & InvApp

'do not use "worksheetfunction" - or will get run-time error if no match
m = Application.Match(MatchTest, InvoiceRng.Columns(1), 0) 'any match?
'test return value for error
If Not IsError(m) Then
    With ActiveSheet.Rows(currentrow)
        .Range("I1").Value = InvoiceRng.cells(m, 2).value
        .Range("k1").Value = InvoiceRng.cells(m, 3).value
        .Range("L1").Value = InvoiceRng.cells(m, 4).value
        .Range("M1").Value = InvoiceRng.cells(m, 5).value
        .Range("N1").Value = InvoiceRng.cells(m, 6).value
    End With
End If
```